# Submitting form after showing div

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have multiple links on a page and clicking on each shows its respective div. Each div contains a form. When I click on the "submit" button on a form, I am trying to write data to another div. I have the jquery in place for writing the form html and showing the div (this is all in the "document.ready" function.) I can't seem to get html in a second div after submitting a form. I've tried

```
$(function() {
     $('#lookup').submit(function() {
         alert("help");
     });
});
```

but that isn't doing anything. Does it have anything to do with the fact that the div was initially hidden? If so, what do I have to do to get around that?  TIA for any help!

Comment: Are you actually submitting anything to a server after showing the div?  if not, then I would use the "onclick" event of the button, rather than submit since submit doesn't alot more things.

Comment: Can you show us your html too and explain in more detail? I think it'll help.

Comment: Good point @ovaherenow. Thanks for that suggestion. Wasn't even thinking along those lines. I'll do that for now. Thank you.